# How to get single values for each column when grouping in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

Assuming the following `DataFrame`:

```
'user' 'val_A' 'val_B' 
'A'    '1'     '2' 
'A'    '1'     '2' 
'B'    '3'     '2' 
'B'    '3'     '2'
```

How can I get single values in columns `val_A` & `val_B` after a `GroupBy user`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `drop_duplicates()`:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
data = """'user' 'val_A' 'val_B' 
'A'    '1'     '2' 
'A'    '1'     '2' 
'B'    '3'     '2' 
'B'    '3'     '2'""".replace("'", "")
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
print df.drop_duplicates()
```

output:

```
    user  val_A  val_B
0    A      1      2
2    B      3      2
```

or if you want groupby:

```
print df[["val_A", "val_B"]].groupby(df["user"]).drop_duplicates()
```

output:

```
          val_A  val_B
user                
A    0      1      2
B    2      3      2
```